# Add "+ / -" to Bootstrap Accordion Panels As Toggle Indicator

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want the group's title to be able to expand into a list or tree, with a text character next to the title that is "+" by default, "-" when expanded, and toggles as the list state is displayed and hidden.

How would I accomplish that in bootstrap v.3?

http://jsbin.com/jakofugoxe/edit?html,css,output

```css
.panel-heading[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse1">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        Collapsible Group 1
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse2">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        Collapsible Group 2
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse3">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        Collapsible Group 3
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Show us some code?

Comment: @Chris he stuck a jsbin up? Should be noted OP has 3.7k rep

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw, you're supposed to add the (relevant) code in the question itself.

Comment: OP: The reason we don't let you post jsbin links by themselves is because you should be adding the code directly in your post (as well as, optionally, a jsbin link). Formatting the link as code to bypass this restriction defeats the purpose and is not OK. Please add the actual code to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `:before` or `:after` pseudo element to draw `+` or `-`:

The `collapsed` class must be used with `.panel-heading` inside all panels except the one that is active. Bootstrap js toggles this class while clicking on panel titles and we can use this to toggle between `+` and `-`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse2">
                      <!--  ^^^ This class should be present on panel headings
                                inside all panels except the one that is active. -->
    <h4 class="panel-title">Collapsible Group 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Necessary CSS:**

```
.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading:after {
  content: '-';
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading.collapsed:after {
  content: '+';
}
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.panel-heading[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading:after {
  content: '-';
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading.collapsed:after {
  content: '+';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse1">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          Collapsible Group 1
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse2">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          Collapsible Group 2
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse3">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          Collapsible Group 3
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```